# SlidingPaneLayout на версиях ниже API17

Tags: android, java

Добрый день.
В своем приложении я решил использовать боковую навигацию, и в качестве контрола взял SlidingPaneLayout. Реализовал на АПИ 17 и все прекрасно работает! Но заказчику необходимо чтобы данный функционал поддерживался на более низких версиях андроид. Перерыл весь гугл в поисках библиотек для интеграции данной опции на более низкие версии андроид, но проблема в том что ничего не нашел! Прошу вашей помощи! Может кто сталкивался с данной проблемой? Или может есть другие способы создания боковой навигации? Буду рад любой помощи!
Вариант с DrawerLayout тоже не подходит, т.к. он работает при minSDKVersion 14.

Comment: работает и на младших, просто в оф примере указана минимальная версия 14, единственное что у меня атм не хотело работать правое меню, двигается все норм, но не держится открытым ... но левое как в вк работает отлично

Comment: Добавил getSupportFragmentManager(): ошибка! The method getSupportFragmentManager() is undefined for the type Main

Comment: А класс `Main` это что? `Activity`? В таком случае, убедитесь, что наследуетесь от `FragmentActivity` из support library.

Comment: public class Main extends FragmentActivity implements
  ListFragmentItemClickListener

Все равно только на 17!

Comment: И в очередной раз повторю вам: давайте стектрейс исключения.

Answer (score 1):

А с чего вы взяли, что `SlidingPaneLayout` не будет работать на API, меньшем 17? `SlidingPaneLayout` входит в состав support library v4, а стало быть, работает на API 7 и выше.

*Updated:*

Да и с `DrawerLayout`, в общем-то, такая же ситуация - от 7 API и выше. Где вы про эти минимальные требования вычитали вообще? :)

Comment: Подключаю support library v4, запускаю на 4.2.2 работает все отлично, перехожу на 2.2 не работает, на 2.3.3 не работает! Ни на девайсах ниже АПИ 17, ни на эмуляторе! Только на АПИ17! И в манифесте рекомендованно прописывать minSDKVersion = 17.

Comment: Что значит не работает? Про Theme.AppCompat не забыли? В общем, без стектрейса исключения дальше это обсуждать бессмысленно, но одно могу сказать точно - оно работает на версиях ниже 17-й, как я и написал выше. А почему у вас не работает - с этим надо разбираться отдельно.

И да, кстати, в сэмпле в SDK, насколько я помню, используется `FragmentManager`, потому и минимальную версию завысили в примере. Замените `FragmentManager` на `support.v4.FragmentManager` и будет вам счастье от 7 API и выше :).

Comment: Я еще использую ActionBar без библиотеки ActionBarSherlock, может быть дело в этом?

Comment: Дайте всё же стектрейс исключения, возникающего при запуске приложения на API < 17. Выясним, в чём причина.

Comment: а ты часом getFragmentManager() не пишешь ?

Comment: Пишу! А что fragment поддерживаются ведь!

Comment: getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.content_pane)
    .setHasOptionsMenu(true);
  getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.list_pane)
    .setHasOptionsMenu(false);

Добавил getSupportFragmentManager(): ошибка!
The method getSupportFragmentManager() is undefined for the type Main

Просто фрагмент:
 <fragment> </fragment>

Вот стать опираясь на которую я писал свой код:
http://gmariotti.blogspot.ru/2013/05/working-with-slidingpanelayout.html

@gadfil Он работает на каких версиях? Я смотрел этот пример! По моему он работает только с 14?

Comment: вот вот  getSupportFragmentManager()  поможет

Comment: а fragment откуда из support library v4 ?
http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html 
немного менять придется но все рабочее, сам по этому примеру писал   
@vanyamelikov  пример да, но я же говорю менять надо с учетом младших версий, код увы не сохранил если по памяти то менять на  getSupportFragmentManager(),  getSupportActionBar() и может еще что то по мелочи,  если только левое меню то замечательно работает